# How can I figure out which pty's are from which qemu?

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, lsof

I'm running qemu's like this:

```
$ sudo qemu -boot d -m 1024 \
-netdev tap,id=tap0 \
-device virtio-net-pci,netdev=tap0,id=vth0 \
-drive file=ubuntu.iso,media=cdrom,cache=none,if=ide \
-monitor pty \
-serial pty \
-parallel none \
-nographic
```

When I check `/dev/pts/`:

```
$ sudo lsof +d /dev/pts/
```

Qemu pty's do not show up, although they do work using for example:

```
$ sudo screen /dev/pts/8
```

How can I figure out which pty's are from which qemu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way using `virsh` along with some scripting:

```
$ for i in `virsh list | awk '{print $2}' | egrep -v "^$|Name"`; do
     printf "%-14s:%s\n" $i $(virsh ttyconsole $i | grep -v "^$");
  done

cobbler       :/dev/pts/1
xwiki         :/dev/pts/3
fan           :/dev/pts/4
mercury       :/dev/pts/5
mungr         :/dev/pts/0
win2008R2-01  :/dev/pts/7
```

Incidentally those same VMs through an `lsof` command:

```
$ lsof|grep qemu|grep ptmx
qemu-kvm   3796      root   14u      CHR                5,2         0t0        993 /dev/ptmx
qemu-kvm   3895      root   14u      CHR                5,2         0t0        993 /dev/ptmx
qemu-kvm   3972      root   14u      CHR                5,2         0t0        993 /dev/ptmx
qemu-kvm   4294      root   15u      CHR                5,2         0t0        993 /dev/ptmx
qemu-kvm  11897      root   14u      CHR                5,2         0t0        993 /dev/ptmx
qemu-kvm  16250      root   15u      CHR                5,2         0t0        993 /dev/ptmx
```

It doesn't look like `lsof` shows which `pty` they're using, just that they're using the `ptmx`. See the [ptmx man page](http://man.he.net/man4/ptmx) for more info.

#### References

- [Setting up a serial console in qemu and libvirt](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/setting-up-a-serial-console-in-qemu-and-libvirt/)

The left side are the names of the VMs and the right side is the `pts`.